# Label in LWC Accordion

Tags: lightning-web-components, accordion, lwc.dev

I'm attempting to customize a label in [lightning-accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-accordion/example). Next to the label I'm trying to place a count that populates from wrapper.

```
 <lightning-accordionSection key={account.id} name={account.name}  label={account.name -recordCount}> CONTENT </lightning:accordionSection>
```

But the label is incorrect. What is a better way to show?

One solution would be to concat the name and  record count as a string and pass it from Apex to UI. But I was hoping for a simpler way to customize the label on the accordion.

Comment: what do you mean the label is incorrect?

Comment: I can only add label={account.name} OR label={account.recordCount} or or I can put label= "\some string". If I deploy using the above syntax, I get an error and says LWC accordion section has incorrect syntax

Comment: oh okay LWC didn't saw the tag

Comment: Your code snippet shows the Aura lightning accordion, you are indeed working in LWC, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, that was a wrong copy paste. I have updated. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of getter property in Lightning web component evaluate the label value. It would be something like:-

```
get labelValue(){
return this.account.name +' - '+ this.recordCount;
}
```

and use this getter in html file as:-

```
<lightning-accordion-section name="B" label={labelValue}>
</lightning-accordion-section>
```

When you are dealing with more than one accordion section, you can create an array of javascript object where object properties can hold the computed label value and run an iteration using **for:each** directive to show accordion section.

```
    get features() {
        return [
            {
                label: this.account1.name +' - '+ this.recordCount1,
                name: 'section 1',
            },
            {
                label: this.account2.name +' - '+ this.recordCount2,
                name: 'section 2',
            },
            {
                label: this.account3.name +' - '+ this.recordCount3,
                name: 'section 3',
            },
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Mine is on a wrapper. So I run a loop in order to get all the values.